# Function design: a logarithm asymptotic to one?

Tags: functions, logarithms

I want to design an increasing monotonic function asymptotic to $1$ when $x\to +\infty $ that uses a logarithm.

Also, the function should have "similar properties" to $\dfrac{x}{1+x}$, i.e.:

1. increasing monotonic
2. $f(x)>0$ when $x>0$
3. gets close to 1 "quickly",
       say $f(10)>0.8$

Comment: Does $1-\frac1{\log\,x}$ not do what you want?

Comment: Uhm, it would be actually great to have a function that "imitates" $\dfrac{x}{1+x}$, in the sense of having also these two additional properties: (1) $f(x) > 0$ when $x > 0$ and (2) which gets close to 1 _quickly_, say $f(10) > 0.8$. Maybe I should edit the question?

Comment: How about $f(x)=1-(\log x/x)$?

Comment: Yes, you should have included those pieces of information in your question to begin with...

Comment: @GerryMyerson, it has to be increasing monotonic.

Comment: @J.M., thanks, I just edited it.

Comment: In $\frac{x}{x+1}$. replace $x$ by some high enough power of $\log(x+1)$ to get the value at $10$ that you desire.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about
$$
f(x)=\frac{a\log(1+x)}{1+a\log(1+x)},\quad a>0?
$$
Notes:

1. I have used $\log(1+x)$ instead of $\log x$ to avoid issues near $x=0$ and to make it *more similar* to $x/(1+x)$.
2. Choose $a$ large enough to have $f(10)>0,8$.
3. You can see the graph of $f$ (for $a=1$) compared to $x/(1+x)$.

[image]

Comment: Is there a name for such a (family of) function?